# *Tensorflow Objection Detection API* mAP calculations for YOLO darkflow?

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, darkflow, yolo

so I would like to use to TF Object Detection API to calculate mAP scores for YOLO.

Currently I'm training my YOLO model and it is producing ckpt files/frozen graph files.

I would like to take my YOLO model and evaluate it using the TF Obj Dec API. I know Eval.py says

---

2) Three configuration files may be provided: a model_pb2.DetectionModel
configuration file to define what type of DetectionModel is being evaluated, an
input_reader_pb2.InputReader file to specify what data the model is evaluating
and an eval_pb2.EvalConfig file to configure evaluation parameters.

Example usage:

```
./eval \
    --logtostderr \
    --checkpoint_dir=path/to/checkpoint_dir \
    --eval_dir=path/to/eval_dir \
    --eval_config_path=eval_config.pbtxt \
    --model_config_path=model_config.pbtxt \
    --input_config_path=eval_input_config.pbtxt
```

---

However, with darkflow there is no model_pb2.DetectonModel Configuration file. Is this possible?